# uivision assistance with regards to css locators

Tags: css, selenium

Morning All

I have two sets of css code on sars websites, where the class complianceClass can either be one or three.

```
<h4 onmouseout="tooltip.hide();" class="complianceClass3 h">
            <a onmouseout="tooltip.hide();" class="trigger" style="display: block;">
            </a>
            <a class="drillDownPlusHead trigger" id="anchorDebt" onclick="changeMeCompliance('drillDownPlusHead', 'anchorDebt');" style="display: block;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;DEBT
                              </a>
          </h4>
```

and the following:

```
<h4 onmouseout="tooltip.hide();" class="complianceClass1 h">
            <a onmouseout="tooltip.hide();" class="trigger" style="display: block;">
            </a>
            <a class="drillDownPlusHead trigger" id="anchorSD" onclick="changeMeCompliance('drillDownPlusHead', 'anchorSD');" style="display: block;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;RELEVANT SUPPORTING DOCUMENTS
                              </a>
          </h4>
```

when using uivision/selenium, I need to look at this class value and tell it if value is compliance class3, then do xyz. I know to get it to do that, using verify element present, but what would the value be used?

so traditionally it would be the xpath of html/div/etc etc but XPath won't work as this does not adjust accordingly, it remains the same. the only thing that appears to alter is the css value above.

I was using a visual verify, but sars website seems to not play nicely with uivision and the image it is told to find, gets cut off when selecting, and what it finds is not accurate as well( finds three potential options, none of which are the correct one).

any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand clearly what you want to obtain. Could you add something like "objective: ..." and "problem: ..."? If you run `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h4').get_attribute('class')` in the first case you obtain `'complianceClass3 h'`, while in the second case `'complianceClass1 h'`

Comment: Uivision has a command called verifylementpresent, which does as it sounds, if the element you specify exists, then it can be told to do other steps, or not if it doesnt exist..

normally this can be a xpath to the particular element, but in this case, the xpath directs to one element, regardless if its complianceclass1 or 3, so this doesnt help as it doesnt differentiate between the two options. you can add the css locator, but I need to know what would the css locator look like if it was complianceclass1/3. will attempt your suggestion, not sure if uivision is that advanced yet

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do. In the question you wrote "I need to look at this class value and tell it if value is compliance class3", running the code I wrote you will know if value is class3 or class1. So it does look like the code answer your question, doesn't it?

Comment: I dont know as uivision is not very clear on this with regards to how to look for a particular css element. for example:

their training document says:

 <button type="button" name="car" value="tesla"> will be matched by the CSS selector css=button[value="tesla"]>.

and that is all. so i thought maybe it would be something like css=class[value="complianceclass1"], but that is a random guess.

Comment: So I have been googling and came across this:

https://www.browserstack.com/guide/css-selectors-in-selenium

particularly the reference to classes, and so the html tag in this should be h4 and the value of the ID attribute is anchorReg? although not sure if that would find what I am looking for

Comment: Ah excuse me, I had assumed that you were using selenium in python, instead you are using selenium ide? The `h4` tag have two attributes: onmouseout and class. So it doesn't have an id. I guess css=h4 should works

Comment: sorry for long time between responses, unfortunately this does not work, as H4 is repeated a few times, in fact it appears of the 4 potential compliant/non compliant options, they all carry the same css code in general, with the compliance class only changing between 1 and 3. the element It found when telling it via a click to look at was id=acc6, seems even uivision on its own sees this as one big element instead